# What to add to manifest to deny Kindle Fire 1st Gen

Tags: android, google-play, kindle-fire

Im having a problem with inputType “numberSigned” and “numberDecimal” cancel each other out, but only on the Kindle Fire 1st gen.

I would like to make sure people in the Play stor get a "This device is not compatible" message so they cannot buy the app. Is there something I can add to the manifest to make sure Kindle Fire 1st gen cannot buy the app?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play is not available on the Kindle Fire devices, so you won't have a problem via Play.

For the Amazon AppStore you can specify developer intent in the developer portal when you upload the app to control if you want Kindle 1st Gen, Kindle Fire 2nd get, Fire HD7 or Fire HD8.9 (as well as non-Amazon devices)

Update: also if you limit the Android API version to, say, a minimum version of 10 you'll exclude the Gingerbread based devices, but include the ICS ones